# "In turn" or "thus" in this situation?

Tags: grammaticality-in-context, synonyms, word-in-context

Considering her service as a adviser in the local administration, it is fair to say she enjoys a degree of social and academic recognition within the regional community. Such recognition must be complemented with this master to increase the relevance of her work to the local authorities. **In turn**, these entities can provide the support necessary for her to explore solutions to the cited difficulties.

Comment: "In turn" and "thus" are two completely different concepts. "In turn" would be better here, since the latter is the result of the happening of the former.

Comment: The text seems to say that A must do something for B, and **conversely** B must do something for A. Neither word seems appropriate.   https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/in-turn https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/thus

Comment: It's a horrible passage, and not good English. Especially the sentence "Such recognition must be complemented with this master to increase the relevance of her work to the local authorities." That is not how "complemented" is normally used: it's normally followed by "by".

Comment: @DhanishthaGhosh both "in turn" and "thus" can be used to express a sequence of cause and effect: X opened the door; in turn Y was able to enter.  X opened the door; thus Y was able to enter.

Comment: Both can be used to introduce the consequences of an action.  The problem here is that it isn't clear what you're trying to express because the writing is generally difficult to parse and on top of that there is missing context.  Therefore (thus?) it's not clear whether either is appropriate.  Therefore (in turn?) I would vote to close, but I do not have sufficient reputation.

Answer (score 0):

I would think *thus* would be a better option here, unless I am not understanding the context correctly. *In turn* implies that something happens after something else. *Thus* implies that something happens as a result of something else.

Comment: I'd disagree. "In turn" suggests a causally-linked succession.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast "thus" also has a sense that conveys causality.  Thus it would also be an appropriate choice here.

Comment: @phoog - Agreed. But my objection was to the implicit assertion that "in turn" does not also have that meaning.